# Replacing Fragment from inside the firebase addOnCompleteListener

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to replace fragment from inside the firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener.

But my application crashes. Please resolve. Here is the code :
FragmentManager fm;

inside on create view :
    fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

userLogin func called from Login button's onClickListener :

```
private void userLogin()
{
    String email = login_email.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = login_password.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) { //email is empty
        return;

    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) { //password empty
        return;
    }
    login_progress.setMessage("Signing in...");
    login_progress.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                login_progress.dismiss();

                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.root, new home());
                ft.commit();

            }
            else{
                login_progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"User ID or Password incorrect!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

}

Simple Toast statement does work on clicking Login. No problem in authentication. Problem in replacing fragment.

Comment: try with `fm = getFragmentManager();`

Comment: same problem persists

Comment: Could you post the crash log?

Comment: added above @Aaron

Comment: I believe your crash is unrelated to firebase, please check again, it has trouble with the menu.

Comment: yeah..right. Thanks @Aaron

Answer (score 2):

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` *"Asynchronously signs in using an email and password."*

You need to make sure any changes to the UI are done on the UI thread.

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null) activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    login_progress.dismiss();

                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.root, new home());
                    ft.commit();

                } else {
                    login_progress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"User ID or Password incorrect!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to implement your method but still the same problem persists- the app crashes.